# On click a link scroll to section and switch tab-pane state to active

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

This is my code:

```
<li><a class="section-link" href="#ex"><strong>1</strong></a>
<li><a class="section-link" href="#ex"><strong>2</strong></a>

<section id="ex">
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">1</a></li>
   <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">2</a></li>
 </ul>

 <div class="tab-content">
<div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
some data
</div>

 <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
some data
</div>

</div>
</section>
```

When clicking the second link,I want the page to scroll to the section "ex" and make the second tab-pane active.

Answer (score 0):

U should try this [startbootstrap-scrolling-nav](https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav), there are all what u need and usage tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I hope scrolling is already working...

use jquery to add class active to the second tab-pane...

add the following code... it runs when you click on any of the li elements ".section-link" and add class active...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".section-link").on('click', function() {
            $('.tab-pane:eq(1)').addClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>
```